# Redirect specific error in stderr

Tags: bash, osx, stderr

So I want to use an `if` statement to run a script to import some functions.

```
$ cat functions.sh
#!/bin/bash

sampleFunction(){
    if [[ ! "${fakeVariable}" == '2' ]]
    then
        read -n1 -r -p "Error! Press any key to continue ..."
    fi
}
sampleFunction
echo "Well, hi!"
```

When I run:

```
if ! 2>/dev/null . "${HOME}"'/functions.sh'
then
    echo "${HOME}"'/functions.sh could not be spawned. Terminating ...'
fi
```

The console doesn't output `Error! Press any key to continue ...`, instead it just sits there, waiting for me to press a key. Once I do, I see `Well, hi` printed.

If `functions.sh` were to be missing from `$HOME`, then it would print:

```
/Users/leetbacoon/functions.sh could not be spawned. Terminating ...
```

as it should.

If I take out `2>/dev/null` and if `functions.sh` exists, I get `Error! Press any key to continue ...` printed out as it should, as well as `Well, hi!` following after I press a key.

If I take out `2>/dev/null` and if `functions.sh` is **missing**, I get:

```
-bash: /Users/leetbacoon/functions.sh: No such file or directory
/Users/leetbacoon/functions.sh could not be spawned. Terminating ...
```

Basically, what I want is this:

```
$ ### functions.sh exists
$ if ! 2>/dev/null . "${HOME}"'/functions.sh' ; then echo "${HOME}"'/functions.sh could not be spawned. Terminating ...' ; fi
Error! Press any key to continue ...
Well, hi!
$ ###
$ ### functions.sh doesn't exist
$ if ! 2>/dev/null . "${HOME}"'/functions.sh' ; then echo "${HOME}"'/functions.sh could not be spawned. Terminating ...' ; fi
/Users/leetbacoon/functions.sh could not be spawned. Terminating ...
```

OS is macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and bash version is 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: Where do you actually _call_ your function?

Comment: When I run your sample code it either prints `Well, hi!` if the file exists or `/home/username/functions.sh could not be spawned. Terminating ...` if the file doesn't exist. It neither prints `Error! Press any key to continue ...` nor waits for input because `sampleFunction` is never called.

Comment: forgot to add that part to the example, just fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Prompts, and any diagnostic messages, are always generated on the standard error stream.  This is to not interfere with possible redirections of ordinary output.  This is also true for the shell's primary prompt (`$PS1`), by the way.

This means that the prompt that `read -p` outputs is *also* written to the standard error stream, and since you redirect that stream to `/dev/null`, you will never see the prompt message.

I would suggest testing for the existence of `/Users/leetbacoon/functions.sh` before attempting to source it:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/functions.sh" ]; then
    . "$HOME/functions.sh"
else
    printf '%s is missing...\n' "$HOME/functions.sh" >&2
done
```

This mimics the way that `~/.bash_profile` sometimes calls `~/.bashrc` and it avoids the "No such file or directory" error.

Note also that the error message that you generate is misleading. Sourcing a file will not "spawn" anything, not even a subshell.

Answer (score 0):

The `read` command uses `stderr` for printing the prompt. Either you have to

1. avoid using `2> /dev/null` when calling the script
2. add `2>&1` to the end of the `read` command to make it use stdout for printing the prompt instead:

```bsh
        read -n1 -r -p "Error! Press any key to continue ..." 2>&1
```